# subversion ankhsvn files disapear from solution explorer

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, svn, ankhsvn

Im using Visual studio 2008. Every once in a while files that exist in the root of couple of my class libraries disapear from the solution explorer on visual studio.

Files exist on subversion. I could not understand the reason of this and it just happened again..

Any one has experienced this problem also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is also reported by TFS users (See google), so it is most likely a Visual Studio bug. It would be nice if somebody found out a way to reproduce this issue. That would finally enable Microsoft to fix this issue.

Comment: Strange.. I have never experienced this under TFS over the last few years and have allready experienced it couple times in two weeks since i switched to svn